# Fluent Validation negate condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation, fluentvalidation

I want to make a rule with Fluent Validation that checks:
if this field contains a Credit Card number then it is invalid (because it contains sensitive data)

Seems easy.

Fluent Validation provides `CreditCard()`  check, but it's the opposite of what i'm trying to do, i searched if there is some kind of negation, like `.Not().CreditCard()` or `.NotMatch()`, but i couldn't find.

There is the idea of making a RegExp that will **not** match only when the field contains a valid credit card, but it seems very unintuitive and unreadable, i wander if there is a more straight forward solution.

Comment: *"Seems easy."* -- if this were easy then FluentValidation would not have needed a [CreditCardValidator](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/main/src/FluentValidation/Validators/CreditCardValidator.cs). The logic is non-trivial. A regular expression would not be enough. You can start with the code in FluentValidation and build your own validator. It would be an interesting challenge.

Comment: CreditCardValidator is not easy, i said that it seems easy to make a function that verifies that it **does not** contain a valid card given the fact that `CreditCardValidator` already exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CreditCardValidator is given for a purpose so that we can avoid saving/processing invalid CreditCard. but with your requirement it seems you would allow to save/process invalid creditcard but will block user for giving valid data.

I am not able to get what is real use case here. could please clarify your usecase.

Update:

you could do something like this.

```
public class MyCreditCardValidator<T> : CreditCardValidator<T>
{
    public override bool IsValid(ValidationContext<T> context, string value)
    {
        bool validCreditCard = base.IsValid(context, value);

        // for my case i want invalid credit card
        return !validCreditCard;
    }

    protected override string GetDefaultMessageTemplate(string errorCode)
    {
        return "field contains credit card";
    }
}
```

and add extension method like

```
public static class CustomerValidatorExtensions
{
        public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> NotACreditCard<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
        {
            return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new MyCreditCardValidator<T>());
        }
}
```

and call like this

```
public CustomerValidator()
{
   RuleFor(a => a.Notes).NotACreditCard();
}
```

now when you provide valid creditcard in the notes field it will fail the validation and return your the error
[image: Request]

[image: error Response]

Hope this helpful.

Comment: Use case: The person at the desk serves the customer then registers him into the system, and, sometimes,  in the field `Client Notes` sensitive data is stored, we want to avoid that

Comment: we already talked with the service desk persons, but we want to prevent it programaticaly

Comment: So as I understand it is not a CreditCard field but free text field "Notes" where user can enter whatever he likes and you want to make sure that you don't store any sensitive information like CreditCard in that field. right ?

Comment: Yes, to comply with PCI security standard

Comment: @ValeriuSeremet- Please check the updated answer for probable solution